# PHP/HTML how to display name to another webpage?

Tags: php, html

when the user input a name to a form. how to display the name to another webpage? 
so i have 2 webpage here it is

webpage 1:

```
 <html>
<body>   
  <form action="lol.php" method="post"  <div id="name">
      <label for="txtname">name: </label>  <br/>
      <input type="text" name="txtname" value="" />  </div>
</html>
```

webpage 2 :

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <p> echo 'welcome! $_POST 
</html>
```

huhuhu so whats next ? :( im kinda new to php please be gentle guys tnx

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the already existing answers: One very important thing to keep in mind is protection against [**Cross Site Scripting** attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). You must assume *"All Input Is Evil!"*. Users might not only enter their name or something like that but also JavaScripts (XSS or even persistent XSS, if you save the inputs) or parts of SQL querys to perform an SQL injection.

Let's say your script accepts a variable called `txtname` from GET or POST (this is what `$_REQUEST` means). And you have this code:

```
<?php echo "Welcome!" .$_REQUEST['txtname']; ?>
```

One could build a link like this:

```
http://yourhost/yourscript.php?txtname=<script%20type="text/javascript">alert("This%20might%20also%20be%20an%20evil%20script!");</script>
```

Then one uses a URL shortening service to build a harmless looking link redirecting to the attacker's URL above, e.g.

```
http://short.xy/dfudf7
```

which will redirect the user to the evil JavaScript link above. Then your website will execute any JavaScript or embedd evil `iframes` or whatever an attacker wants. Your users / customers will only see your website in the address bar and will think all that comes from you although a hacker added malicious parts to the site they view.

Therefore, whenever you output something that comes directly or indirectly from a user input (regardless whether read by `$_REQUEST` or fetched from a database), you have to make sure, HTML special chars like < and > don't work any more! php offers the function [htmlspecialchars](http://us.php.net/htmlspecialchars) to **escape** these dangerous characters. Then they are displayed just as text and do not function as HTML/JavaScript.

By the way, this is not a protection against SQL injections. If you plan to use a database later, you will also have to look for that. Also in this area there are functions to "demine" a user input before passing it to a database.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to close `<form>` tag, missing to add `submit` button, I have fixed your form and it should be like...

**webpage.html**

```
<form action="lol.php" method="post">
<div id="name">
      <label for="txtname">name: </label>  <br/>
      <input type="text" name="txtname" value="" />
      <input type="submit">
</div>
</form>
```

**lol.php**

```
<?php echo "Welcome!" .$_POST['txtname']; ?>
```

**NOTE**

You can also use `$_REQUEST` to print name..

```
<?php echo "Welcome!" .$_REQUEST['txtname']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Page : 1

```
<html>
<body>   
  <form action="lol.php" method="post"  <div id="name">
      <label for="txtname">name: </label>  <br/>
      <input type="text" name="txtname" value="" />  </div></form>
</html>
```

Page : 2

```
<?php
echo "Welcome ".$_POST['txtname'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to close `<form>` tag, missing to add `submit button`

**webpage.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="lol.php" method="post" name="form" id="form">
        <div id="name">
          <label for="txtname">name: </label>
          <br/>
          <input type="text" name="txtname" id="txtname" />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**lol.php**

```
<?php
if((isset($_REQUEST['submit']) && trim($_REQUEST['submit']) =='Submit'))
{
    $txtname = addslashes(trim($_REQUEST['txtname']));

    echo "Welcome ".$txtname;
}
?>
```